# Looking for a Python solution to identify rows where correct sequence is not matching using pandas or regex

Tags: python, pandas

Extract the sequence (row) where the correct sequence does not match by using pandas or regex in python

| ref_nbr | Date | extracted_seq | correct_seq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FGR0 | 2022-05-02 16:24 | '0312' | '0123' |
| FGR3 | 2022-05-02 16:29 | '0312' | '0123' |
| FGR1 | 2022-05-02 16:32 | '0312' | '0123' |
| FGR2 | 2022-05-02 16:36 | '0312' | '0123' |

==> Above is the dataframe I have.

I am looking to extract the row where the index position of **extracted_seq** is not matching with **correct_seq**. So the output should be 2nd row since this is where the correct_seq failed to match.

| ref_nbr | Date | extracted_seq | correct_seq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FGR3 | 2022-05-02 16:29 | '0312' | '0123' |

Comment: Since the columns have all the same string values, it is not clear why row 2 'does not match'

Comment: Hi @user19077881, the row 2 does not match because it is the first raw that is out of order. The correct_seq is 0123 and row 2 has ''ref_nbr'' ending with '3' so it is the first instance that correct_seq is failed so the output is 2nd row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As both the _seq columns have all the same value, you can just extract one value from each then step-through until you find the mismatch and use the index of the mismatch to select the row of interest:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ref_nbr': ['FGR0', 'FGR3','FGR1', 'FGR2'],
                   'Date': ['2022-05-02 16:24','2022-05-02 16:29','2022-05-02 16:32','2022-05-02 16:35'], 
                   'extracted_seq': ['0312','0312','0312','0312'],
                   'correct_seq': ['0123','0123','0123','0123']
                   })

print(df)

s1 = df.loc[0,'extracted_seq']
s2 = df.loc[0,'correct_seq']

for i, x in enumerate(s2):
    if x!= s1[i]:
        dfx = df.iloc[[i]]
        break

print(dfx)
```

or if the character value rather than its position in the string which is important then use

```
dfx = df.iloc[[int(x)]]
```

Comment: Hi @user19077881, I am getting this error: 
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

Comment: My code now edited to add the example DF as from your question so you can check it works for you. 
Which line in your code is giving the error? Is your DF using the default numerical row index?

Comment: Yes, it was. And now the code worked as expected. Thanks so much @user19077881